# How to change herokuapp.com domain to another herokuapp.com domain

Tags: heroku

I have deployed a Django app to heroku and I want change the default herokuapp.com domain. I don't want to use a custom domain, just another herokuapp.com domain.

On settings page of my app I tried adding another heroku domain using the `Add domain` button but I get this popup
`Can't add an additional Heroku domain`

Is there anyway to change this without starting a new Heroku app using a new name?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way apart from just moving everything to a new app.

In general the `.herokuapp.com` domain shouldn't be used for your users, but only internally.